# change the css of certain divs using classname

Tags: jquery

I am trying to alter the css of certain divs on a page using a classname.

the issue is that the classes with the name of "content_container" won't become visible

EDIT: The issue is with `var deleted_content = $(this).closest('.deleted_content_unique_id').attr('value');` It is not setting the variable for some reason.

here is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/die20/uUudM/16/

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: content_unique_id is not a class in your html but name attribute

Comment: It seems your CSS modifies the divs, not the input elements inside them. Also, I wouldn't use visibility, as it causes a lot of issues. I'd use display: none/block instead.

Comment: When you repeat things like this several times (`$(this).closest('.content_container')`), use variables.

Comment: Please mention what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: the issue is that the classes with the name of "content_container" won't become visible.

Comment: The HTML you provided is not complete, at least not for us to imagine the complete usability Here is an example of what we can imagine: http://jsbin.com/ehitor/1/edit

Comment: I edited the code. sorry

Comment: ok, where is your `.deleted_set` ? http://jsbin.com/ehitor/2/edit

Comment: at the bottom of the html.

Comment: That that is also your issue, cause you're targeting a `sibiling` and `.deleted_content_unique_id` is not a `.deleted_set` sibling. Can you create a test case on jsBin? or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you provided isn't very clear but this is a simple example of how to loop through child elements and hide only ones that meet a criteria:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="hide #2" id="hide">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-hide="false">1</div>
    <div data-hide="true">2</div>
    <div data-hide="false">3</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#hide").on('click', function () {
    $('#wrapper').children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-hide') == 'true') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sEpkU/

Also note that you are referencing a class name of `.content_unique_id` but that is not a class in your HTML it is an attribute. To select divs based on an attribute you'd use:

```
$("[name='content_unique_id[]']")
```

Comment: I just updated the jquery based on your input. still having issues.

Comment: If you want help, you need to use describe your issues in greater detail. Most often, people put their code into http://jsfiddle.net to highlight the problem. Copy a SIMPLE example of the problem you are having into jsfiddle and post a link.

Comment: I made a jfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/die20/uUudM/2/   still having issues :(

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/uUudM/17/